# Jquery convert object keys/values into functions parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, object, parameters

Is it possible to convert a object like so:

```
{'para1':'hey','para2':'wow'}
```

into parameters using the same keys inside a function like so:

```
window['test']({'para1':'hey','para2':'wow'})
```

using function:

```
function test(para1,para2){alert(para1);alert(para2)}
```

instead of:

```
function test(parameters){alert(parameters['para1']);alert(parameters['para2'])}
```

result:

> hey wow

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I'm really confused.  The `window['test']()` looks like it is try to invoke the test method on the window object (which could just be `test()` or `window.test()`).  In which case your question seems to be asking if you could take that object and pass it in as an argument, which the answer is yes ...

Comment: I want to change the object into a set of parameters using the same keys

Comment: Javascript does not map input names to function parameter names.  There is no restriction or mapping between the two parts.  It is entirely positional based.

Comment: Change function({'para1':'hey','para2':'wow'}) into function(para1,para2)

Comment: Alright, thank you.

Comment: `window.test(parameters)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use object destructuring for this:

```js
function test({ para1, para2}) {
  alert(para1);
  alert(para2)
}
test({ 'para1': 'hey', 'para2': 'wow' })
```

Comment: Sorry, I understand. Yes this is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

did you mean dynamic input params?

```js
function test() {
    var i;
    var result = '';
    for(i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
      if(typeof(arguments[i])=='object'){
        for(ob in arguments[i])
          result += arguments[i][ob] +' ';
      }
      else result += arguments[i] +' ';
    }
    return result;
} 

var inObj = {'para1':'I', 'para2':'Love', 'paraMore':'You'};

alert(test(inObj));
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can use eval function to add variables in a dynamic form:

Try this:

```
function Test(object){
    Object.entries(object).forEach((entry) => {
        eval(entry[0]+' = "'+entry[1]+'"');
    });

    Object.keys(object).forEach((entry) => {
        eval('console.log('+entry+')');
    });
}

Test({'eric': 'hello'})
```

This should print hello